# Perl: making an array ref out of a scalar variable inside of a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

Can anybody please let me know how can I make an array ref out of a scalar variable (equivalent to a hash ref)? The code I have so far is:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $index=0;
my $car={};

$car->{model}[$index]="Tesla";
my $texxt = $car->{model}[$index];
@{$texxt}=qw(1 2 3);

print "@{$texxt}";
```

This gives the following error: 
Can't use string ("Tesla") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test99.pl line 8.

Basically I am trying to make an array (or an array ref) called "@Tesla" that has values (1 2 3).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what kind of datastructure you want to have in the end. Hash of arrays? Hash of hashes? Can you elaborate? *c.f.* [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hash with a key called "model" that contains an array with "Tesla" as the first element and an anonymous array as the second element (and `texxt` as a short cut reference to that) then this would work

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $index=0;
my $car={};

$car->{model}[$index]="Tesla";
my $texxt = $car->{model} ;
push @{$texxt} , [qw(1 2 3)];

print ref eq "ARRAY" ? "@{$_}" : "$_ " for @{$texxt} ;
```

output: `Tesla 1 2 3`

You can use [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) to view the data structure in a nicely formatted way:

```
use DDP;
p $texxt;
```

outputs:

```
\ [
    [0] "Tesla",
    [1] [
        [0] 1,
        [1] 2,
        [2] 3
    ]
]
```

This can help you visualize what perl is doing to your data.

Answer (score 0):

If $texxt is a string (it's not a hash ref), you cannot dereference it as an array. You can assign an anonymous array to it, though:

```
$texxt = 'Tesla';
$texxt = [qw[ 1 2 3 ]];
```